# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when trying to download maven dependencies from private nexus

Tags: maven, jdk6

I'm using maven in my **JDK6 project** (Cannot upgrade to 7 or above).
In this , i'm trying to launch **maven clean install**.

I'm so getting this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.12.1:check (check-code) on project XXXXX: 

org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.2 -> commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1: 
Could not transfer artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:pom:1.1.1 from/to mycompany-mirror
 (http://nexus.mycompany.dns/repository/maven-mycompany): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure ->
```

I'm using current settings.xml format file :

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>com.mycompany.corp.framework.maven</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>

<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy-priv</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>GROUP\myUsername</username>
      <password>xxxxxxxxxxx</password>        
      <nonProxyHosts>xxxx.mycompany.dns</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxy-priv</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>GROUP\myUsername</username>
      <password>xxxxxxxxx</password>        
      <nonProxyHosts>xxxxx.mycompany.dns</nonProxyHosts>          
    </proxy>        
</proxies>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>mycompany-mirror</id>
        <name>mycompany Nexus Repository</name>
        <url>http://nexus.mycompany.dns/repository/maven-mycompany</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>mycompany_repo</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>releases</id>
                <name>Nexus Managed Releases Repository</name>
                <url>http://nexus.mycompany.dns/repository/maven-releases/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>

            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>Nexus Managed Snapshots Repository</name>
                <url>http://nexus.mycompany.dns/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>releases</id>
                <name>Nexus Managed Releases Repository</name>
                <url>http://nexus.mycompany.dns/repository/maven-releases/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>

            <pluginRepository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>Nexus Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
                <url>http://nexus.mycompany.dns/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>maven_3_2</id>
        <properties>
            <maven32>true</maven32>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>downloadSources</id>
        <properties>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mycompany_repo</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>maven_3_2</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

The problem is that some dependencies are downloaded successfully => **thats why i'm sure my credentials are correct & i have access to nexus**. But some others not.

I also tried to **download ssl certificate from nexus and to add it to my security\cacerts** with keytool . Everything is ok.

I tried to use some collegue's settings.xml , with same error. (It is working for them).

Any suggestions ?